# LDA / ROL / STA - Instructions explanations

Tags: 6502

Can someone explain what exactly result on each instruction LDA,ROL,STA gives a results?

```
C=1 (carry flag is 1)

LDA A #$08 0008 | 01
ROL A      0009 | 02
STA A $10  000A | 03  // A result is $11
           000B | 04
           000C | 05
```

I think of this:

```
LDA A #$08 0008   - Store 0000 into memory
ROL A      0009   - Get a data 0x08 from accumulator 0000 0100 add carry +1 = 0000 1011
STA A $10  000A   - get a result 0000 1011 = $11
```

Is it correct, explanations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't quite understand the listing, but the instructions work as follows:

`LDA #$08` loads $08 into the accumulator, setting the N and Z flags according to the value loaded.

`ROL A` rotates the accumulator left 1 bit, putting the old carry flag into bit 0 and putting the old bit 7 into the carry flag. $08 shifted left 1 bit is $10, and since the carry flag was 1, the end value is $11. (The N and Z flags are also set according to the new result.)

`STA $10` stores the value of the accumulator into memory at address $10, leaving the accumulator unchanged. The flags are unaffected.

(It's not usual to write something like `LDA A #$08` - the fact that A is involved is known from the mnemonic, LDA being short for **L**oa**D** **A**ccumulator. `ROL A`, on the other hand, is written like that because `ROL` can also access memory. The 6502 assembly language syntax is just not very consistent by modern standards.)

6502.org has some good reference material - e.g., http://www.6502.org/tutorials/. If you've done assembly language programming on other systems you'll probably be good to go just from the data sheet from, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502#Further_reading.

Answer (score 1):

Tom has given a good description. I would add that some assemblers use "A" for operations on the accumulator (e.g. ROL A) and some don't (just ROL).

So here's a commented disassembly:

```
SEC      ;I added this to set C=1
LDA #$08 ;Loads immediate value 08 into A and sets status flags (as every instruction does)
ROL      ;Rotates (like a shift) A left through the carry, so C=0, A=0x11
STA $10  ;Stores A into memory address $10, so $10=11
```

You can test your program in various simulators or emulators that have debuggers - just step through and watch each instruction's effects. That's the best way to learn.

Copy the above disassembly and paste it in [here](http://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/). Click "Assemble", check the "Debugger" check box and click "Step". The web page is an ebook to teach you 6502 programming with built-in simulators.

Alternatively [this simulator here](http://e-tradition.net/bytes/6502/) is not too bad.

[Clicking this link](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert.html?a=0000&d=a9082a8510) will load your program into a more advanced simulator which shows every cycle.

Of course there are many other downloadable emulators of old computers where you can interact on the command line to enter assembly and then use the emulator to debug it. This requires a bit more learning, but might be worth it. E.g. [AppleWin](https://github.com/AppleWin/AppleWin) is a reasonable choice as it's quite easy to use.

Comment: Thanks! This is a better