# Does a 6502 register load (LDA, LDX, LDY) modify the N and Z flags in immediate addressing mode?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I know that `LDA`, `LDX`, and `LDY` instructions typically set/clear the (N)egative and (Z)ero flags based on the byte value that gets loaded into the register. I thought I remember reading somewhere that this is NOT the case with immediate addressing (e.g. `LDA #$0F`), but can no longer find reference to that. It doesn't seem like setting the flags on such operations would add any value, so it would make sense if it doesn't. I don't know if I am misremembering.

Comment: Neither [this site](https://c64os.com/post/6502instructions) nor [this site](http://6502.org/users/obelisk/6502/reference.html#LDA) call out any special case for loading immediate. They say that LDA modifies flags in all modes. That behavior is consistent with my experience. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085174/lda-rol-sta-instructions-explanations/42092814#42092814) also confirms that `LDA #$xx` updates flags.

Comment: Duplicate of [LDA / ROL / STA - Instructions explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42092814) ?  Or do we need a more authoritative answer if there isn't another one on SO already?  Perhaps some 6502 simulators have test programs that have been verified to run the same on real 6502 hardware as on the simulators, which exercise this corner case?

Comment: @PeterCordes That question is not an exact duplicate but the answer to this one is given in the answer to that question. Anyway [Visual 6502](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert.html) confirms that the flags change

Comment: As an adjunct, confirmed that this is tested by — at a minimum — the Wolfgang Lorenz test suite and [my own](https://github.com/TomHarte/ProcessorTests/tree/main/6502). I'd also be amazed if it weren't in AllSuiteA and the Klaus Dormann tests.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get an old Apple IIc up and running, and have since confirmed (on a 65C02 anyway), that the load instructions DO affect the N and Z flags in immediate addressing mode.